# Why does my Bison parser consume all the tokens and then stops, without executing the actions?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am creating a parser to parse XML start tags. Here is an example of a start tag:

```
<person name='John Doe'>
```

My lexer tokenizes that start tag to this sequence of token-kind/token-value pairs:

```
'<'
NAME/person
NAME/name
'='
QUOTED_VALUE/'John Doe'
'>'
```

Below are my Bison grammar rules. I only show the action for the attribute rule, which prints the name of the attribute:

```
attribute: NAME '=' QUOTED_VALUE { printf("Attribute, attribute name = %s\n", $NAME); }
```

Bison generates the parser without errors. When I run the parser, the action for the attribute rule isn't executed.

I ran the parser in debug mode; I show its output below. The debugger shows that the parser processes the tokens and then stops, without executing the actions (e.g., the printf statement isn't executed). Why is that? What am I doing wrong, please?

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Stack now 0
Reading a token
Next token is token '<' ()
Shifting token '<' ()
Entering state 1
Stack now 0 1
Reading a token
Next token is token NAME ()
Shifting token NAME ()
Entering state 5
Stack now 0 1 5
Reading a token
Next token is token NAME ()
Shifting token NAME ()
Entering state 8
Stack now 0 1 5 8
Reading a token
Next token is token '=' ()
Shifting token '=' ()
Entering state 13
Stack now 0 1 5 8 13
Reading a token
Next token is token QUOTED_VALUE ()
Shifting token QUOTED_VALUE ()
Entering state 17
Stack now 0 1 5 8 13 17
Reducing stack by rule 10 (line 44):
   $1 = token NAME ()
   $2 = token '=' ()
   $3 = token QUOTED_VALUE ()
```

Here are my Bison grammar rules:

```
start: start_tags  { ... } 
;

start_tags: start_tag               { ... }
  |         start_tags start_tag    { ... }
;

start_tag: '<' NAME '>'                  { ... }
  |        '<' NAME "/>"                 { ... }
  |        '<' NAME attributes '>'       {...  }
  |        '<' NAME attributes "/>"      { ... }
;

attributes: attribute             { ... }
  |         attributes attribute  { ... }
;

attribute: NAME '=' QUOTED_VALUE    { printf("Attribute, attribute name = %s\n", $NAME); }
;
```

Comment: Presumably something is blowing up in the execution of that reduction action. It could be that the semantic value of the `NAME` is invalid (NULL or unmapped memory.) Or that you overwrote a buffer or double-freed or some other UB, leaving the library's internal data structures inconsistent. Unless you provide a [mre], no-one but you will ever know. (Haven't we covered this before?)

Comment: Thank you @rici Based on your comment, I took a closer look at my action for the rule for attribute and sure enough I was trying to access unmapped memory. You're amazing! Wow!